# What is the difference between hadoop, mongoDB, Big data?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

What is the difference between Hadoop, MongoDB, Big data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 different things.

Hadoop is a framework. Something you use to develop an entire application.

MongoDb is a db. A nosql one. It is where you store data.

BigData is a concept. It is related to huge quantity of data. Where huge is not a fixed parameter. 4 mb was huge in 1960. Now huge means several terabyte.

Comment: big data is when you can't insert it into excel :)